# How to excel at math?

Tags: education, book-recommendation, advice

I know this question has been asked at least a hundred times earlier but before you mark this as duplicate please read this cause I seriously need some professional help here.

I'm a 15 year old kid who is pretty good at all other subject expect math. I am considered as smart but being self aware that I am not smart cause I am only just above average at math. I am a curious kid and I always was. I don't know where it went wrong but I failed somewhere.

Let me tell you something about my past. I started pre school at 4. I wasn't taught properly by my parents or family at home the only piece of education I got was from my school which was little less than four hours daily. I don't know if you guys are taught at home when you were young but in my local it it doesn't work like that every kid is taught from home more than that of school. But I remember that I was able to read and write way before than friends. I didn't care for math till recently because I was not challenged by it,I wasn't able to conceive it practical purpose which was clearly my teachers' failure I always ask my teacher "What this is used for ?" and she would answer "don't care about it". As I said am pretty curious and I think about everything so deeply, that's how I learn things.

I didn't attend school that much when I was young so I missed some basic arithmetic and I wouldn't ask anyone if had a doubt,I just pretended I knew it. I was always interested in science, especially physics I realised that it needed math so I started studying math last year even though I didn't like it. I also got interested in computer science recently and it need math too. So I've been pushing myself into studying it but it too obvious and I think it won't help studying if I don't love what I am doing.

I definitely got better at math recently cause I was terrible before. I got better at reasoning and problem solving lately but when it's from I syllabus I kinda fail. My teacher is good but she ain't the best,she just gives us many examples while not teaching a single bit of theory at all. I can't learn something clearly without knowing its meaning. Now let me compare my marks in math and other subjects,if I get 95 in science or any other subject, I would've gotten 85 in math. I don't know what's wrong with me, Am I math anxious or am I just stupid? As I mentioned above,I am kinda improving at math but i feel like it's not enough. I can go on and on but this is already longer than what I expected and I don't wanna make it tedious. I hope you will give me advices which would literally change my life cause I couldn't think of a career without mathematics.

Comment: I read it as it is but others won't be so kind, seeing a wall of text incoming they will close the question without reading a single line !

Comment: How much maths you know ? Calculus ?

Comment: @A---B yeah I know :(

Comment: What makes you think you are stupid because you have $85%$ on maths? This is a good grade?

Comment: @A---B no just the school stuff but I've been trying to learn calculus recently but I am confused where to start with

Comment: @Math_QED not good enough for me

Comment: Math is a very structured subject, it's not possible to master it by jumping all over the place, Sounds like you've missed some basics and that will cause difficulties, you need to build your math skills from the ground up. It's never too late to start learning.

Comment: @Vasya I've been doing that lately and it is effective

Comment: if necessary go thru text books from the previous grades all over again and find what you've missed. Solve a lot of problems, logic puzzles and play logic-oriented games that develop analyzing skills. It's possible to catch up but you need to invest your time in it.

Comment: @Vasya I think I have pretty much cleared my basics and I am pretty good at chess but I would like to move on to something bigger

Comment: You might want to take a look at the book "A Mind for Numbers" by Barbara Oakley.  Good ideas for improving your math skills.

Comment: @awkward what about How to solve it by polya

Comment: "How To Solve It" is excellent. I recommend it highly.  It covers different ground than "A Mind for Numbers".  AMFN is more about psychology, HTSI more about mathematics.

Comment: @awkward I just started reading A mind for numbers

Comment: Great!  I guess you know, "Mind for Numbers" is the text for a Coursera's open online "Learning How To Learn" course.  I have not taken the course, so I don't know whether to recommend it or not, but you might check it out.

Comment: @awkward I'm pretty good at learning new things hope this won't conflict with the existing mental model I have

Comment: @awkward reading the book is enough,right?

Comment: If you are asking if the book alone is sufficient without the online course, I think I benefited from just reading the book. But would the online course provide additional value?  I don't know.  You could always try it and find out.  What the heck, it's free.

Comment: @awkward What do you think of the book did it really improve your math skills?

Comment: I don't know that I can say that the book has improved my skills (yet), but I can tell you that I wish I had read the book long ago, back when I was in school.   I think the book has some worth-while ideas to improve one's learning skills.

Comment: @awkward okay I've started reading it but I don't know how long I'll be reading it coz I am only good at starting something and not in ending I hope I find it interesting

Comment: Maybe you should skip directly to Chapter 5, "Preventing Procrastination" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether people on this site (myself included) can give you
better advice than people at school who know more about you than you have
been able to summarize in your Question. So here are some things to think about.
Perhaps take some as advice. Perhaps ignore others.

(1) I'm not sure whether starting to learn calculus at 15 is the best
choice. Calculus may go better when you know some trigonometry and
analytic geometry--and maybe patch a few gaps in your algebra.

(2) As you encounter things in math classes or independent reading that you
don't understand, try to figure out if there are gaps in your background
that may account for the difficulty and how you can go back and fill in the gaps.

(3) Because you're interested in uses of math in addition to theory, maybe
look into aspects of physics, computation, statistics, and
probability where math that interests you is used for various purposes.

(4) Think about the mechanics of solving problems: Here are a couple of
suggestions to get you started. (a) Given the equation of a line and the coordinates of a point
that is not on the line, can you compute the shortest distance from the point to the line? (b) Can you figure out the sum of this series? $1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + \cdots .$ (c) Given the equation of a parabola, can you figure out whether
it crosses the x-axis? (d) What points in the plane satisfy $|x|+|y| \le 1?$ You might look on this site for other problems and solutions.

(5) When you run into an interesting math problem you can't solve, consider
posting it on this site. Say what you have tried and what is puzzling you.
Explain that it's for self-study, not a homework assignment. Maybe someone
will give you an interesting and helpful answer.

(6) If there is a library at your school or in your town with some math
books, consider browsing around to see if you can find interesting topics
at your math level. I think books are more reliable sources of worthwhile math
ideas than most stuff on the Internet.

(7) There are some books available online for free that are written by
very good mathematicians who write well. One of them is Grinstead and Snell: *Intro to Probability,* which has interesting historical notes and doesn't require
calculus. The PDF of the whole book is available free on the Dartmouth 
website. Maybe other people on this site can suggest other free (or inexpensive) books that
might worth looking at.

(8) If you keep finding new math topics that interest you and keep patching
gaps in the old ones, I think one day you may be advising others how to excel in math.

Comment: That's a pretty good advice. Wish I had some kind of map for studying math step by step

Comment: Btw I can answer the first three but not the last because I hadn't been taught that yet. I am good at leaning new things but not sure where to start with

Comment: Do you know about absolute values? Question (d) is similar to asking what $(x,y)$ points satisfy $x^2 + y^2 \le 1,$ which is the points in a circle of unit radius with center at the origin $(0,0).$ // Those particular problems aren't important, but that you can answer (a)-(c) does tell a bit about your background. // The point is to be on the lookout for similar problems and learn from solving them. // A step-by-step guide should come after discussion with someone who knows you pretty well. // Wishing you success in your study of math.

Comment: maybe I should request for a map in another question

Comment: Seems difficult to recommend a useful personal study outline working at a distance and not knowing more about you than fits in a web page.

Comment: I don't know what happened but recently I've been very good at math and I thought part of it came from self confidence

Comment: That can play an important part. Wishing you continued success.

Comment: thank you :),other part was that I really didn't like it until now and it's hard for me or anyone to be good at something they don't love

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to solve various math problems which involve elementary level of calculus algebra trignometry, etc. And trust me if will start loving math math will start loving you. Do problems and discuss them with instructor or here at math SE. If you want you can connect with me also. I am pursuing MS in mathematics. Will love to help you. And yes don't be grades oriented. If you love math then only you get best grades. And believe me math will help you to achieve number of milestones.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I've been saying the same thing for a long time " I love math but math don't love me"

Comment: How can you say that? Any example

Comment: Please accept my answer.

Comment: @ChiragMittal Don't force anyone to accept an answer. This is bad policy.

Comment: Sorry it will not happen again